# how to detect custom urls of a third party application from bbm and email link in blackberry java

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

Requirement: when the user presses enter on e.g. `bbApp001://screen1?param1=1234567890?param2=12345678`

where `bbApp001` is one of the apps in the device; `screen1` is one of the screens that is created in the app; and `param1` is the first param that is sent along with the link and same with the `param 2`.

In a BBM message or in the email the corresponding application will be invoked with that as context.

1. how to detect custom `urls(bbApp001://screen1)` of a third party application from an email or bbm link in blackberry
2. if above can be done then how to send content with links to email and bbm so that when a user click the corresponding app is launched
   Note: for the first - I have tried to launch from another application using  `ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("bbApp001?screen1&param1")` but my requirement is to trigger/invoke the app once the user click on email or bbm message.

Comment: Take a look to content handler api

Comment: how to add and invoke from an email and bbm message

Comment: as soon as user press it it will invoke appropriate content handler

Comment: @EugenMartynov <br/> Jus a few queries <br/>                     1.how to add a custom url to a bbm message and email and give a click functionality for eg: if I add the below code and send, I am not able get as html content <br/> <a href = "bbApp001://screen1">click</a>

Comment: My fault it's not CHAPI API. Take a look on these two links: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-Protocol-Handler/td-p/335240, http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Leverage_pattern_matching_in_BlackBerry_smartphone_applications_to_provide_an_integrated_user_experience.html?nodeid=1234285&vernum=0

Comment: @EugenMartynov I had come across these links before but I wasn't sure how to test, integrate and achieve to my requirement. Anyway, thnx for taking time to reply, I shall analyze and post the queries if any as I come across. Thnx again.

Answer (score 0):

It's explained here. Please try and let us know.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Launching-Blackberry-Application-via-a-Custom-URL-Scheme/td-p/1395479